# Animated gif with wxpython phoenix

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I was trying to put an animated gif in a wxpython panel but apparently there is no animarion nor adv package in my wxpython version:

```
In [1]: import wx
In [2]: wx.version()
Out[2]: '4.0.1 gtk3 (phoenix)'
```

Then i tried to use the gif as a `wx.Bitmap` but of course it would not play. I know that according to phoenix documention:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html

the gif handler class is MISSING, but i was wondering if there is any way to use a gif (threding maybe?) in phoenix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wx.adv contains `Animation` and `AnimationCtrl`
Ripped out of the demo's

```
import wx
from wx.adv import Animation, AnimationCtrl

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        anim = Animation('/home/rolf/loveyourjob5qj.gif')
        ctrl = AnimationCtrl(self, -1, anim)
        ctrl.Play()
        sizer.Add(ctrl)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test=wx.App()
    TestPanel(None)
    test.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use your code, do you have any idea why my kernel crashes? I tried different Gif files, my Wxpython version is 4.0.4 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5 and i use Python 3.

Comment: @K-Doe None at all. I re-tested this code on Linux python 3.6.7 wx 4.0.4 gtk2 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5. I also tested it against wx 4.0.1 gtk3. Both work without issue. You don't say how your kernel "crashes"

Comment: Thank you for testing. Sadly my IDE doesnt give me any further information. If i run the code i see that it starts, but no window appears and after ~2sec it shows `Kernel died, restarting` not more.

Comment: @K-Doe Have you considered that it may be your environment? What happens it you run it on the command line?

Comment: Thats it. I tested on two computer and both had the same problem. On the third, at home, everything went well. Now i know its the environment. Thank you!

Comment: This can't be used in the bitmapbutton, right?